# Connection error after attempting to upload or move a file with FileZilla

Tags: putty, sftp, filezilla

I've started using Putty and FileZilla on my windows 10 notebook to access a cluster server.

I was able to log in yesterday and had success moving, downloading and uploading some small files, but it suddenly aborted the connection after a tried to download a pbs file. So when tried to log in FileZilla with a SFTP connection it gives me a "Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity" and with Putty it just gives me a black screen and then a Network error.

Today I could log in normally and then it happened again when a tried to upload a .fastq file.

I checked my Firewall and tried changing the timed out connection to 30 seconds, but it did not work.

I really need this to analyse some metagenomic data. Thank you!

Comment: I can log in normally using my university's wifi connection. The problem is at home, my 2 notebooks can't log in. Could it be a wifi permission problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. I was using a public network, and it was blocking my connection when I attempted a file transfer. So I just changed de wifi properties to a private network.